# apply function only works on the first 1000 rows of pyspark.pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a df that has roughly 6 million points and one column, it is a df that I converted to a pyspark.pandas df. Whenever I use apply on each row, it only does the function on the first 1000 rows I dont know how to stop this. Can anyone help me. I would use a normal spark df but my column has numbers as column names and spark wont accept this. Can anyone help

Heres the code:

```
import ast
import os

import findspark
import pyspark.pandas as ps
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

df = pd.read_parquet(
    "training_data_fv_unlabeled_spark_libsvm.parquet", engine="fastparquet"
)

os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"] = "True"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args
os.environ["PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE"] = "1"

memory = "100g"
pyspark_submit_args = " --driver-memory " + memory + " pyspark-shell"


findspark.find()
findspark.init()
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Get the default configurations
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()

# Update the default configurations
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll(
    [
        ("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "500G"),
        ("spark.executor.memory", "200G"),
        ("spark.app.name", "Spark Updated Conf"),
        ("spark.executor.cores", "5"),
        ("spark.executor.instances", "5"),
        ("spark.cores.max", "8"),
        ("spark.driver.memory", "500G"),
    ]
)

# Stop the current Spark Session
spark.sparkContext.stop()

# Create a Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "500")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "500")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")


def fv_to_dict(row):
    fv_str = row
    fv_str = "{" + fv_str.replace(" ", ", ") + "}"
    dict_str = ast.literal_eval(fv_str)
    out = _parse_dict_ket_to_str(dict_str)
    # dict_list[index] = dict_str
    dict_list.append(out)


dict_list = []

psdf = ps.DataFrame(df)

psdf.apply(lambda row: fv_to_dict(row), axis=1)
```

This code stops in 4 seconds and dict_list has a len of 1001 always. I dont know how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
df = pd.read_parquet('training_data_fv_unlabeled_spark_libsvm.parquet', engine = 'fastparquet')

import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

import os
memory = '100g'
pyspark_submit_args = ' --driver-memory ' + memory + ' pyspark-shell'
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args


import findspark
findspark.find()
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import random
import os
os.environ["PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE"] = "1"
spark  = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#Get the default configurations
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()

#Update the default configurations
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '500G'),( 'spark.executor.memory', '200G'), ('spark.app.name', 'Spark Updated Conf'), ('spark.executor.cores', '5'), ('spark.executor.instances', '5'), ('spark.cores.max', '8'), ('spark.driver.memory','500G')])

#Stop the current Spark Session
spark.sparkContext.stop()

#Create a Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "500")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "6000")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")

import pyspark.pandas as ps

import ast

def fv_to_dict(row):
    fv_str  = row
    fv_str = '{' + fv_str.replace(" ", ", ") + '}'
    dict_str = ast.literal_eval(fv_str)
    out = _parse_dict_ket_to_str(dict_str)
    #dict_list[index] = dict_str
    dict_list.append(out)

dict_list = []

psdf= ps.DataFrame(df)

psdf.apply(lambda row: fv_to_dict(row),axis=1)
```

Comment: I didnt seem to work, would you have any more suggestions? Thanks for the attempt!